# How to POST Json to a Play Framework Morphia controller

Tags: json, playframework, morphia

I first tried using play 1.2.4 with morphia 1.2.6a to post json data to my controller. That always ended with a null pointer exception somewhere inside play, so I switched to play 1.2.3 and i got a bit further, but am still confused. The post call now succeeds but the data never seems to arrive.

route

```
    POST /mytest    mycontroller.myposttest
```

mycontroller.java

```
    public static void myposttest(SampleObject item){
       Gson gs = new GsonBuilder().create();
       System.out.printf(gs.toJson(item));
       //NOTE: item is empty every time
    }
```

mytest.java

```
    String jsonText = "{name=\"foo\"}"; 
    Response response = POST("/mytest/","application/json",jsonText);
    //NOTE: the post call succeeds but the jsonText data is not found on the other side
```

The examples I have read show this as just working, but I have been messing with this for a very long time and have not figured it out. How is this intended to work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Play cannot bind Json to object direclty
2. Your post data has no parameter named "item"

You should change your post code to:

```
Response response = POST("/mytest/","application/json",{item: jsonText});
```

And your controller code should be:

```
public static void myposttest(String item){
    Gson gs = new GsonBuilder().create();
    SampleObject obj = gs.fromJson(item);
    obj.save();
    ok();
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and the string value was empty. I must be doing something wrong, but I cannot see it.